# Hide and show checkbox issue in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, checkbox

I have a `Checkbox` in a `ListView` to select items and I have one `Button` outside the `ListView`. Initially the `Checkbox` should be hidden, when I click that `Button` the `Checkbox` should display in the `ListView` and vice versa.

I have one issue in that, when I press the `Button` initially it displays one `Checkbox` and again I press the `Button` it show a few checkboxes but what I want was initially it should be invisible when I press the `Button` it should be visible in `ListView`

Note: I have a `Button` in class and `Checkbox` in adapter

```
sdel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

            ((datalist) mlistView.getAdapter()). toggleChecks();
            ((datalist)mlistView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

});
```

```
public void toggleChecks() { 

   for (int i = 0;i<sms.size();i++) {
        holder.cb.setVisibility(CheckBox.VISIBLE);
   } 

   isCheckBoxVisible=!isCheckBoxVisible;
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you explain it simply ?

Comment: i have one fragment class and adapter class in that adapter i set one checkbox to select/deselect and i have one button in class (outside the listview).initially the checkbox should be in hide state and when i click the button it displays ...simple @ 0X0nosugar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create  model for this purpose
in that define getter setter for boolean variable

```
private  boolean isVisible;

public boolean isVisible() {
    return isVisible;
}

public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    isVisible = visible;
}
```

in activty set this flag as false by default

```
YourModel model=new YouModel();
 for (int i = 0; i <sms ; i++) {

        model.setVisible(false);
    }
```

In adapter write condition for check box
//assuming sms is arraylist

```
YourModel model=sms.get(position)
if(model.isVisible){
checkbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else{
checkbox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

now on button click write below code
//if checkbox is visible

```
  for (int i = 0; i <sms.size() ; i++) {
            sms.get(i).setVisible(false);
        }
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

//if checkbox is invisible
  for (int i = 0; i <sms.size() ; i++) {
            sms.get(i).setVisible(true);
        }
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: am using holder to get the values  and i have button in outside the listview