# Recyclerview with two checkbox (yes or no) in Android

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

How to get the position of particular checkbox(yes or no) in each row of a recycler view I am able to get the position of row wise checkbox but on scrolling both (yes and no) checkbox are getting checked.

((CheckBoxViewHolder) holder).chkNo.setOnClickListener(new 
View.OnClickListener() {

```
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ((CheckBoxViewHolder) holder).chkYes.setChecked(false);
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    RatingQues contact = (RatingQues) cb.getTag();
                    contact.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                    ratingQuestions.get(position).setSelected(cb.isChecked());


            ((CheckBoxViewHolder) holder).chkYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ((CheckBoxViewHolder) holder).chkNo.setChecked(false);
                   CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    RatingQues ratingQues = (RatingQues) cb.getTag();
                     ratingQues.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                    ratingQuestions.get(position).setSelected(cb.isChecked());
```

Comment: use on check change listener in chekbox

Comment: then how to get the position of particular checkbox can you elaborate the solution

Comment: Please add a screenshot or xml file of the layout, and your adapter class

Comment: [IMG]http://i63.tinypic.com/dpa2l5.png[/IMG] screen shot of my adapter class

Comment: @Himanshu it's not a good way to attaching screenshots, better to copy and paste code in your question.

Comment: Now review my code Neo thnx fr showing interest

Comment: i tried ur solution neo still not working

Answer (score 2):

Maintain a model for the current status, for example -

```
class MyModel{
    String status;
    boolean isChecked;
}
```

Now tag position with every checkbox, in onBind. So whenever you getChangeListner just change in model. Also bind checkbox as per model flag value.

Hope it will help, let me know if you need further help :)

Comment: Okay, first do one change, set tag position only, so once you have the position you can easily access the question and all thing. Now on chngeListener of yes, get tagged position from view and change the model `ratingQuestion.get(position).isSelected = true;` and on click of no set as false. hope it will help you :)

Comment: Did you tried my solution? No need to change the model.

Comment: And if you need help in code, kindly edit your post and add your adapter code.

Comment: radio button will work in this situation *bold*`chHolder.radioGroup.setTag(newInteger(position));chHolder.rGrp.check(questions.get(position).getSelectedRadioButtonId());chHolder.rGrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(newRadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {@Override public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {int radioBtnID = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();selectedPos = (Integer) group.getTag(); questions.get(position).setSelected(true);
questions.get(selectedPos).setSelectedRadioButtonId(radioBtnID);}});chHolder.rGrp.check(questions.get(position).getSelectedRadioButtonId());`

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38177900/hide-and-show-checkbox-issue-in-android/38178088#38178088) answer you can go with two Boolean variable and instead od visibility use setchecked(true/false)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `SparseArray` to record which one you have already checked.